# Why the "Terminal" in Terminal Aerodrome Forecast?

Tags: taf

Why isn't it just called Aerodrome Forecast? Where does the "terminal" part come from?

Comment: Because aerodromes are where flights terminate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Terminal refers to the airspace near the airport, more or less similar to the ATC usage of terminal as in "terminal airspace" or area. TAFs cover the airspace in a 5 mi radius of an aerodrome, the immediate terminal area. The T in METAR also refers to terminal as in "Meteorological Terminal Aviation Routine Weather Report".

Comment: Also in ATIS and [FAA is using Area](https://www.acconline.org//documents/3bforecastingsession_devoti.pdf) instead of Aerodrome sometimes.